# Problema com html5Mode angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-routes

Montei minha aplicação `Angular` usando `#!` na url dos links, agora estou tentando utilizar o `html5Mode` porém não está funcionando.

A estrutura de pastas da minha aplicação está assim: Na raiz está o `index.html`, uma pasta com as imagens, uma pasta com o `CSS`, uma pasta com os arquivos `JS` que estou usando(o próprio `angular.min.js` e `jQuery`) e uma ultima pasta chamada `app` onde estão os `controller`, `directives` e `services` do Angular.

Já inseri `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` no meu `app.js` que é onde defino o nome do meu modulo e as rotas. No arquivo `index.html` (que é onde está o `<ng-view />`) inseri o `. Quando faço isso as imagens do site somem todas e os links param de funcionar.

Comment: Que tipo de servidor você está utilizando? Ex.: Eu uso apache e foi necessário uma configuração no arquivo .htaccess também. Sobre as imagens e css sumirem, tente adicionar `/` no inicio do href, veja se resolve.

Comment: Ainda estou com ela na minha maquina, não subi pra nenhum servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema do html5Mode. O meu  estava apontando para um endereço errado de pasta do meu projeto. Agora está ok!